# Recommendation on contructing the left menu bar similar to show in FullCalander demo

Tags: fullcalendar

In the FullCalendar demo, https://fullcalendar.io/#demos
you can see the left menu bar to try various features.

a. How can we create something similar. Basically we need to have menu with each sub menu containing like checkboxes and other specific components (somethings hyperlink, buttons, etc).

I guess we want to replicate the implementation in the demo

b. Is there a worked example of FullCalendar we can access? Especially source code of Demo or anything else that is available. That would speed up the implementation process.

Comment: Yes most of the demos on fullCalendar's website have links to codepen containing source code. and the main source code of the project is available on GitHub. If you copy anything make sure you keep to the license conditions

Comment: Or are you asking about how to recreate the actual menu bar from that page which contains the links to all the demos? It's not quite clear from your question. The menu is just part of the website, not part of the fullCalendar product itself. If you want to know how that works, just inspect the source code of that page using your browser's Developer Tools

Comment: Thanks. I meant menu bar on the left of the calendar on the demo page. It contains items like drag n drop elements, etc.

Comment: Ok well as I said above, that menu is just part of the fullCalendar product website, not part of the fullCalendar system itself. So if you want to know how that works, just inspect the source code of that page using your browser's Developer Tools